# E: $y^2+y=x^3$ an elliptic curve over $F_{2}$. How to prove the number of $E(F_{2^n})$ = $2^n+1$ if n is odd, ....

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Let E be the elliptic curve $y^2 + y = x^3$ over $F_2$. 
Prove

$
$#E($F_{2^n})$$ = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            2^n+1 & \quad n=odd  \\
            2^n+1-2(-2)^{n/2} & \quad n=even
        \end{array}
    \right.$

I discovered $E(F_2)$ = {$\infty$  , (0,0), (0,1)} 
but from there I have no idea where to begin in honesty.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the zeta function?

Comment: I don't think so, because zeta function is derived from the formula above.

Comment: If you're allowed to use the big theorem about zeta functions of elliptic curves, then you can prove this fact by looking at finitely many cases (I think $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$ suffice). You don't need to compute $E(\mathbb{F}_{2^n})$ for all $n$ to compute the zeta function.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see your point. It seems to be discussed in this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144194/update-how-to-find-the-order-of-elliptic-curve-over-finite-field-extension?rq=1

Comment: For the odd case you don't need the zeta function, because $x\mapsto x^3$ is a bijection. Not sure about the even case.

Comment: No we haven't talked about the zeta function in this class. I guess that one like you gave talks about the Frobenius endomorphism. I'll talk a closer look because we have discussed this endomorphism before.

Comment: If you have a solution using the zeta function I'd like to see it though, I do know what it is.

Comment: @AdamStaples, I think the zeta function solution is exactly the one you posted - the proof of the theorem has Hasse-Weil L function lurking behind. On the other hand, you can also proceed by Jacobi sum. The case where $n$ is even is already done by Jyrki Lahtonen above, and the case where $n$ involves a Jacobi sum for the cubic characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem: Let #$E(Fq) = 1 - a + q $  Write $X_2 − aX + q = (X − α)(X − β)$. Then

# $E(F_{q^n}) = 1 − (α^n + β^n) + q^n $

for all n ≥ 1.

Now for the problem:
It is easy. Write  $x^2 + 2$ = $(x+i \sqrt2)(x-i \sqrt2)$ and so

#$ E(F_{2^n})=$ $2^n+1 -(x+i \sqrt2)(x-i \sqrt2)$

and from there it is then easy to use a phase argument to duduce the answer.

Note: $X_2 − aX + q$ is known as the Frobenius characteristic polynomial.